# How to enable excel export button for jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, export-to-excel

Hello
I want to show "export to excel" button in the pager of jqgrid. I tried many ways, read many articles/posts, but I don't see this button. Documentation does not have anything useful too. Which actions should I do to see this button

Ps. I use ASP.NET MVC

PSS. my code is

```
<link href="../../Scripts/jquery.UI/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-ru.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>


<table id="EmployeeTable">
</table>
<div id="EmployeeTablePager">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#EmployeeTable').jqGrid({
            url: '/Employee/EmployeeData',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            jsonReader: {
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                root: "rows",
                repeatitems: false,
                id: ""
            },
            colNames: ['Id', 'Имя', 'Фамилия', 'Email', 'Date'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', width: 20 },
            { name: 'FirstName', width: 105 },
            { name: 'LastName', width: 100 },
            { name: 'Email', width: 150 },
            { name: 'Date', width: 150, formatter: ndateFormatter }
            ],
            pager: '#EmployeeTablePager',
            excel: true,
            viewrecords: true
        }).jqGrid('navButtonAdd',
        '#EmployeeTablePager',
        { caption: " Export to Excel ",
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-bookmark",
            onClickButton: genCSV, position: "last"
        });
    });
    function genCSV() {
        alert('a');
    }

    function ndateFormatter(cellval, opts, rwdat, _act) {

        var time = cellval.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//, '$1');
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(time);
        return date.toDateString();
    }

</script>
```

but I don't see the excel import button.
http://ru.magicscreenshot.com/jpg/t97BDzCIO0Q.html

why?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming markup of

```
<table id="jqgrid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Something along the lines of

```
$('#grid')
    .jqGrid({ 
             datatype: "clientSide", 
             height: 190, 
             colNames: headers, 
             colModel: model, 
             multiselect: true, 
             pager: '#pager',
             pgbuttons: false,
             pginput: false,
             caption: "Random Data",
             deselectAfterSort: false,
             width: 930
    }) 
    .jqGrid('navButtonAdd', 
            '#pager',
            {caption:" Export to Excel ", 
            buttonicon:"ui-icon-bookmark", 
            onClickButton: genCSV, position:"last"});
```

`genCSV` will be  a JavaScript function that will make the call to the controller action to generate a CSV file.

Here's **[an example](http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/VxpHf/)**, in combination with jQuery flot. Create some data, select some grid rows and then click the generate graph button in the bottom left of the grid to plot the points. Note that this will not work in Internet Explorer less than 8 as it requires support for the HTML 5 canvas element (and I haven't bothered to include excanvas).

**EDIT:**

Your markup is not working because you need to initialize a navGrid before being able to set a custom button (**[see note on page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons)**). You can do this like so

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#EmployeeTable').jqGrid({
        url: '/Employee/EmployeeData',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        jsonReader: {
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            root: "rows",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: ""
        },
        colNames: ['Id', 'Имя', 'Фамилия', 'Email', 'Date'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', width: 20 },
        { name: 'FirstName', width: 105 },
        { name: 'LastName', width: 100 },
        { name: 'Email', width: 150 },
        { name: 'Date', width: 150, formatter: ndateFormatter }
        ],
        pager: '#EmployeeTablePager',
        excel: true,
        viewrecords: true
    })
      /* Need to initialize navGird before being able to set any custom buttons */
      .jqGrid('navGrid', '#EmployeeTablePager', {
        add: false,
        edit: false,
        del: false,
        search: false,
        refresh: false
    }).jqGrid('navButtonAdd',
    '#EmployeeTablePager',
    { caption: " Export to Excel ",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-bookmark",
        onClickButton: genCSV, position: "last"
    });
});
function genCSV() {
    alert('a');
}

function ndateFormatter(cellval, opts, rwdat, _act) {

    var time = cellval.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//, '$1');
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(time);
    return date.toDateString();
}
```

Comment: the same result :( any ideas more?

Comment: @user285336 - it is working, take a look here - http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/7H3xC/ the only thing that I've changed is to replace the AJAX to fetch data with 'clientSide', but you can see the button is there

Comment: do copy/paste to my new test page - does not see excel import button!!! Why it can be? Maybe js/css files? Which files do you include?

Comment: I have set the following paragraphs during download jqgrid http://ru.magicscreenshot.com/jpg/mRKpgs9hjk4.html and http://ru.magicscreenshot.com/jpg/dW4IxbEQK0Y.html . Version of jqgrid 3.8.2

Comment: I have included all modules, download and it works!!! documentation is invalid, says only "Import/Export" and "XML/JSON" modules

Comment: how do I disable the export feature?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to create a csv file on the server and display a download link next to the grid in my view.

It's not as slick as what you have in mind but it is quick and easy to implement.

Extension method to create a csv file from a list (from another post on SO):

```
    public static string AsCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
                                     where T : class
    {
        var csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            //string line = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null).ToCsvValue()).ToArray().Join(",");
            string line= string.Join(", ", properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null).ToCsvValue()).ToArray());
            csvBuilder.AppendLine(line);
        }
        return csvBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private static string ToCsvValue<T>(this T item)
    {
        if (item is string)
        {
            return string.Format("\"{0}\"", item.ToString().Replace("\"", "\\\""));
        }
        double dummy;
        if (double.TryParse(item.ToString(), out dummy))
        {
            return string.Format("{0}", item.ToString());
        }
        return string.Format("\"{0}\"", item.ToString());
    }
```

Controller:

```
            model.AListOfData.ToArray().AsCsv();

            using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(errorFilePath))
            {
                sw.Write(values);
            }

            model.ErrorFullFileName = errorFilePath;
```

In the view:

```
<%=Html.ImageLink("", "AssetUpload", "DownloadErrors", "/?filename=" + Model.ErrorFullFileName, "/Content/Icons/excel.png", "Download errors and warnings", "imagelink")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it works pretty well

```
            jQuery("#table_resultats").jqGrid('navGrid', "#yourpager").jqGrid( //#pager
            'navButtonAdd', "#yourpager", {
            caption : "Excel export",
            buttonicon : "ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s",
            onClickButton : null,
            position : "first",
            title : Excel export,
            cursor : "pointer"
        });
```