# how to convert a jqgrid data to excel

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, export-to-excel

Hi in my `MVC3(Razor)` application am using `Jqgrid` and `JSON` as its input.
I want to `export all the data into excel`.
Is there any method to `export jqgrid to excel` or `export JSON to excel`?
If any body knows please share.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526331/how-to-enable-excel-export-button-for-jqgrid. Although it is highly recommended to do this all server side of possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) you will find the code and the description why I think that one should use [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) on the *server side* instead of the usage of some kind of conversion in jqGrid (on the *client side*).